# Angular CLI - External scripts minification

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm able to add an external js file in the project.

This issue I have is that Angular-cli minify the file and I don't want that. What property can I add to disable that minification ?

```
 "scripts": [
    ...
    { "input": "../node_modules/external-lib/external-lib.js",
      "output": "assets/vendor/external-lib" }
  ],
```

Comment: Remove it from ng cli scripts section in ng cli.json and add it to your index.html directly and put it in assets folder

Comment: I really need it to be part of the build;